# MVC Razor - Setting model values to other model values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have 2 models in a view. I want to be able to set a value of one of the attributes of the model to the other model attribute while going through the for loop. Example code for clarification:

```
@model xxx.Models.modelbundle
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Post", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
{

    for (int item = 0; Model.One.Count > item; item++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.One[item].ObjectId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Two[item].set)
            </td>


           @Model.Two[item].ObjectId = Model.One[item].ObjectId; // Here. How to set them?


        </tr>

                }


    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="button" value="Change Me" href="/Admin">

        <div></div>
    </div>
}
```

Edit:

ObjectId will not be passed through to Model.Two. Eg

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post(modelbundle model)
    {
        List<Two> list = model.Two; // Model bundle contains a list. Eg. model.Two[0].ObjectId = null
      ...
}
```

Model-Two (Inside modelbundle):

```
public class 
{
    public bool get { get; set; }
    public bool list { get; set; }
    public bool set { get; set; }
    public bool delete { get; set; }
    public bool all { get; set; }
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public string displayName { get; set; }
}
```

---

With David's help - this is what worked for me. I'm aware it could be done without the blue/yellow variables but it makes it easier (for me) to read.:

```
 @{
                var yellow = Model.One[item].DisplayName;
                Model.Two[item].displayName = yellow;

                var blue = Model.One[item].ObjectId;
                Model.Two[item].ObjectId = blue;

            }
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Two[item].displayName);
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Two[item].ObjectId);
```

Comment: Why are you setting model properties *in the view*?  That should be done before the model is sent to the view.  Granted, this no reason this shouldn't work.  (How have you confirmed that it doesn't?  In the code shown you never reference the property that you updated.)  But there's also no reason to do this in the first place.

Comment: I know this doesn't work as the ObjectId in my model always comes back null. Also, because I'm changing/ editing the attributes in the model here with the check box - I wanted to get it in the right place (does that make sense?) and pop it in the same loop. :)

Comment: "comes back null" *where*?  The code shown never references that property after it's been set.  You need to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Edited. Is that any better?

Comment: Where on the page do you have any inputs for `model.Two[0].ObjectId`?  The model being passed into the action method is only going to have what the page sent.  If there are no form elements which contain that value, then that value won't be passed to the server.  I think you're confused about the separation of server-side and client-side code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(modelbundle model)
{
    //...
}
```

The `model` variable will *only* have what the client-side page sent it.  Nothing more.  So, for example, this client-side input is sending a value for this property:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Two[item].set)
```

However, this doesn't create any sort of client-side markup at all:

```
@Model.Two[item].ObjectId = Model.One[item].ObjectId;
```

All that line does is set a property on the instance of the model which was passed to the view.  If that property is never used while rendering that view, it's going to be lost as soon as the view finishes being built and that instance of the model falls out of scope.

Structurally, the *concept* would be similar to this:

```
void Method1()
{
    var something = new SomeObject();
    Method2(something);
}

void Method2(SomeObject obj)
{
    obj.SomeProperty = "some value";
}
```

The property is successfully set, but as soon as `Method1()` finishes executing it's lost because nothing ever used it.  That instance fell out of scope and is now gone.  When you create a new instance of `SomeObject` later (as the model binder does in ASP.NET when receiving the request from the client), that *new* instance isn't going to have the change you made to a previous instance.

Circling back to your web application... In order to include that value in what's being posted back to the server, the value would need to be included in the form being posted.  Something like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.Two[item].ObjectId)
```

This will render a `<input type="hidden" />` which contains the value to be posted with the form.  Note of course that, since this value is going to come from the client, users *can* edit that value.